# SSRS: Export to PDF - Top Margin is too big

Tags: reporting-services, printing, export-to-pdf

I have a report that requires specific formatting so that it can print to a page of Avery labels. I have set up the report to be two tables side by side to represent the two columns of labels. When I export the report to MS Word and print, the items line up perfectly within each on label on the actual sheet. However, when I export to PDF, my top margin is too big so the alignment with the labels on the paper is off. Does anyone know how to make the PDF export respect my top margin?

Page Size: 8.5in x 11in

Margins:

- Top = 0.505in
- Bottom = 0.3in
- Left = 0.24in
- Right = 0.31in

Comment: Is the top of each table 0?

Comment: @JerryRitcey: Do you mean the Location.Top property? If so, then yes, I have set the Location.Top = 0in for both tables.

Answer (score 2):

SSRS honors two major render formats. First, the **soft page-break render** includes the report preview, Word, Excel, and HTML and is more designed for reports which are displayed on a screen. To the contrary, the **hard page-break** format is utilized by pdf and image format among others, and is more designed for physical printing of reports. A soft break render uses InteractivePageSize as a guide for displaying the report and generally ignores the Margin settings; the hard break format adheres strongly to the PageSize settings and also to the Margins.
These are the main features of each one:

Soft page breaks:

- Margins are not applied
- Inserted, explicit, or forced page breaks are honored
- Report sizes can adjust to include orphaned and oversize objects in a report

Hard page breaks:

- Pages moves left to right and then top to bottom
- Inserted, explicit, or forced page breaks are honored

  - Items that are set to keep together may still be pushed to a next page if not enough spaces exists

These two render formats are driven by two report properties found in the Page Category section of report properties.  The InteractiveSize Width and Height control the size of the soft page-break render formats. When an object is displayed using one of the hard break renderers, then the PageSize and Margins properties are used.

[image]